# Can someone tell me why this shell script isn't working the way I want it to

Tags: bash, sh

```
ssh hostname ps aux| egrep '.*python' | grep -v 'grep'| awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill -KILL
```

When I run this I get the error message "kill: No such process"

But when I run this:

```
ssh hostname ps aux| egrep '.*python' | grep -v 'grep' |awk '{print $2}'| xargs echo
```

It correctly prints the pid. And also

```
ps aux| egrep '.*python' | grep -v 'grep'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -KILL
```

works correctly on the localhost.

Comment: Don't use `ps` and `grep` when `pgrep` will do. And don't use `pgrep` and `kill` when `pkill` will do.

Answer (score 3):

Your command is only running `ps aux` on the remote host, everything else gets executed locally.

change it to

> ssh hostname "ps aux| egrep '.*python' | grep -v 'grep'| awk '{print \$2}'| xargs kill -KILL"

The usage of the quotes sends the entire command over to the remote host. And then you have to add the `\` in front of the `$2` because youre inside double quotes, and those single quotes are just characters at that point

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, you can't just run a piped command through `ssh` without putting the command sequence in quotation marks.

But there's an even easier way to do what you want:

```
ssh hostname pkill python
```

The `pkill` command will handle all of the process grepping for you.

Comment: My egrep pattern is a little more complicated than what I posted. pkill and pgrep would not correctly match the regex in my pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It can't work that way, the output from ssh is processed on your local machine. So the call to kill will try to terminate a process on your machine, not on the remote machine.

You can try to use the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) tool to solve the problem.

Comment: how about ...|ssh hostname xargs kill -KILL ?  Or, rsh hostname '<whole pipe>' with appropriate cautions on quotes inside quotes

Answer (score 0):

It's because only first command (ps aux) is being provided to ssh as args. Try to use quotes: 
ssh hostname "ps aux| egrep '.*python' | grep -v 'grep'| awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill -KILL"

In this case "ps aux| egrep '.*python' | grep -v 'grep'| awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill -KILL" would be passed to ssh command as 2nd argument